# How to execute href based on javascript confirm() output

Tags: javascript, dom, href

i have a link as follows:

```
<a onclick="deleteCourseLink()" href=examcont?action=RemoveCourseLinkAction></a>
```

and the `deleteCourseLink()` method is as follows:

```
   function deleteCourseLink(){


              if(!confirm('${textResources['ListCourseLinks.DeleteMessage']}')){
                    return false;
                }
          }
```

i want to execute the href only if the return value of the method is true, i.e when the return value is false(when cancel is pressed) nothing should happen, any idea about how to do that ?

Comment: For future reference, it helps if you say *what your code currently does / what about it isn't working*, as well as what you want to happen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you saying that the question does appear, but then the link doesn't get cancelled even if they press <kbd>Cancel</kbd>?

If so, just change the link to:

```
<a onclick="return deleteCourseLink()" href=examcont?action=RemoveCourseLinkAction></a>
```

(added the word `return`).

The rest of your code is correct (assuming `${textResources['ListCourseLinks.DeleteMessage']}` is a server-side variable?).

Although you could choose to simplify it to:

```
function deleteCourseLink(){
    return confirm('${textResources['ListCourseLinks.DeleteMessage']}');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
onclick="return deleteCourseLink()"
```